# rails: Create does not work with :through in third model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, insert, dependencies, has-many-through

So I have a nested resource with

```
resources :albums do 
  resources :elements
end
```

I can update, delete and view those elements.
What I can not really do is to create a new element.
So it is actually created in the database but not in the mapping table.
Models:

class Album:

```
has_many :elements, :through => :albums_elements      
has_many :albums_elements
```

class Element:

```
has_many :albums_elements
has_one  :album, :through => :albums_elements
```

class AlbumsElement:

```
belongs_to :album
belongs_to :element
```

In the element Controller I have:

```
def create
@element = Element.new(params[:element])
@album   = Album.find(params[:album_id])
respond_to do |format|
  if @element.save
    format.html { redirect_to album_elements_path(@album), :notice => 'Element was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :json => @element, :status => :created, :location => @element }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.json { render :json => @element.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

So as I said, when I press the create button in the form, the element is being created correctly in the table "elements", but not inserted into "albums_elements".
I saw a similar post here, where the author was told to fix his dependencies.
But I don't see an error in mines?
How do I tell rails to insert into both tables?
elements AND albums_elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please check by relating your `@element` and `@album` in `elements_controller` class? Like you already have

```
@element = Element.new(params[:element])
@album   = Album.find(params[:album_id])
```

Just add

```
@element.album = @album
```

Now `@element.save` should insert a entry in your relationship table also.

Let me know if it works. I've just answered after a glance to the problem.

**Clarifications:**

I will try to make a sample app for you. But before that i need to know some more.

- Seems the relationship between `Album` and `Element` is `one-to-many`, then why you are using `has_many :through`? It could be simply `Album: has_many :products` and `Product: belongs_to :album`.
- If you must use a relationship table, does it have any other attributes?
- Is it OK if I provide any solution of `one-to-many`?

I will try to provide you the best rails way to save these entries asap. 
Thnx

Comment: Oh I did not see the reply, sorry. Unfortunately not working.
The log says: 
NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for #<Album:0xe85e92a8>):
  app/controllers/elements_controller.rb:46:in `create'
It looks like this:
@element = Element.new(params[:element])
 @album   = Album.find(params[:album_id])
 @element.album = @album
Now, not even element was created

Comment: I also had to change the element model to: 
has_many :album, :through => :albums_elements | instead of | has_one :album, :through => :albums_elements - but the problem is still there.

Comment: I solved it by using an own insert on the relationship-table:
new_element = Element.last
element_id = new_element.element_id
AlbumsElement.create!(:album_id => params[:album_id], :element_id => element_id)

Comment: Great !! But this is so manual. I am sure that there is much more easier solution for this. I will try to make a sample of that shortly. But before that, would you please clarify my questions added to my answer?

Comment: Very nice thanks.
So the relationship table must be used ... in fact it is possible, that 1 element also belongs to many albums - so it is many to many :through the relationship table.